# How to change the fill rule of SKShapeNode when filling color

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, cgpath, skshapenode

I'm using **SKShapeNode** to create a view element which is used in my game, it should be like the following picture, with only 2 visible curves and fill color inside.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    override func sceneDidLoad() {

        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode()
        shapeNode.fillColor = .red
        shapeNode.strokeColor = .white
        shapeNode.lineWidth = 5

        let path = CGMutablePath()
        let radius:CGFloat = 250
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:0, y:300), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi*7/6, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*11/6, clockwise: false)
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:0, y:-300), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi*1/6, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*5/6, clockwise: false)

        shapeNode.path = path

        self.addChild(shapeNode)
    }
```

But I got an extra straight line on right side which is not I want.

[image]

So I tried to move to another arc directly

```
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:0, y:300), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi*7/6, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*11/6, clockwise: false)
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x:cos(CGFloat.pi/6)*radius, y: -300+sin(CGFloat.pi/6)*radius))
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:0, y:-300), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi*1/6, endAngle: CGFloat.pi*5/6, clockwise: false)
```

I got something like this, which is not I want either.

[image]

I've learned that I can change the fill rule of **CAShapeLayer** by using **CGPathFillRule** after checking Apple documents, but I have no idea how to connect **SKShapeNode** and **CGPathFillRule**.

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the fill rule is going to fix things here. You need a way to separate the portions of the border that you want stroked.  Simplest is probably to create two shape nodes, one done as in your first case and filled, and a second done as the second case and stroked.

Comment: Would probably need 3,  one for the top arc, bottom arc, and fill

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Based on their bottom picture, I gather that the moveTo works to make two separate strokes for top and bottom arcs.

Comment: No, that is because the path is not closed.  His move to goes to x of 1*radius, so that has to be the right side

Comment: Nevermind, I got the lines wrong (mobile is not friendly),  it is jumping without completing the line, but it is completing the path from top left to top right... which then gives me an idea

Comment: Two shape nodes work fine, is there a more efficient way? if no, I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: The only thing I can think of the might be a bit more efficient (after setup) would be to make a node with the two shape nodes as children, render it to a texture using the view's `texture(from:)` method, and then create a regular sprite node from that texture.